# How to achieve zero downtime with Passenger 3?

Tags: unix, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger

In the technology preview posts about Passenger 3 they discussed zero downtime:

> In Phusion Passenger 3 we’ve
>   implemented zero-downtime web server
>   restart. Phusion Passenger and the web
>   server are restarted in the
>   background, and while this is
>   happening, the old web server instance
>   (with the old Phusion Passenger
>   instance) will continue to process
>   requests.

From what I understood, when using Passenger 3 no requests are delayed or dropped during deploy time. But from my tests with Passenger 3 and nginx this is not true. What I'm experiencing is that already made requests are completed, but new requests that are being made when deploying are delayed and waiting for Passenger to spawn new instances.

What I was expecting is that the old Passenger instances will keep serving requests until the new one is fully ready to accept incoming requests.

Did I misunderstand their explanation or I have some bad configuration?

Just to clarify, I understand that I can achieve zero downtime with multiple servers, but in this case I'm referring to one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See following comment by Phusion CTO

http://blog.phusion.nl/2010/06/18/the-road-to-passenger-3-technology-preview-2-stability-robustness-availability-self-healing/comment-page-1/#comment-22181

Comment: Thanks. His comment clarifies that I misunderstood what they mean by "zero downtime", although even after reading his comment I still don't understand at what cases I will have zero downtime. Or did they just mean that no connections will be dropped?

Comment: You are right about 'no connections dropped'